# SQL - Query to return active subscriptions on a given day

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I have a table that shows when a user signs up for a subscription and when their membership will expire. A user can purchase a new subscription even if their current one is in force.

```
userid|purchasedate|expirydate
1     |2019-01-01  |2019-02-01
2     |2019-01-02  |2019-02-02
3     |2019-01-03  |2019-02-03
3     |2019-01-04  |2019-03-03
```

I need a SQL query that will GROUP BY the date and return the number of active subscriptions on that date. So it would return:

```
date      |count
2019-01-01|1
2019-01-02|2
2019-01-03|3
2019-01-04|3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT day, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) active_subscriptions 
FROM (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(purchasedate) min_date, MAX(expirydate) max_date FROM `project.dataset.table`),
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_date, max_date)) day 
JOIN `project.dataset.table`
ON day BETWEEN purchasedate AND expirydate
GROUP BY day
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 userid, DATE '2019-01-01' purchasedate, DATE '2019-02-01' expirydate UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2019-01-02', '2019-02-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2019-01-03', '2019-02-03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2019-01-04', '2019-03-03' 
)
SELECT day, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) active_subscriptions 
FROM (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(purchasedate) min_date, MAX(expirydate) max_date FROM `project.dataset.table`),
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_date, max_date)) day 
JOIN `project.dataset.table`
ON day BETWEEN purchasedate AND expirydate
GROUP BY day
```

with below output

```
Row day         active_subscriptions     
1   2019-01-01  1    
2   2019-01-02  2    
3   2019-01-03  3    
4   2019-01-04  3    
5   2019-01-05  3    
6   2019-01-06  3    
... ...         ...
... ...         ...
31  2019-01-31  3    
32  2019-02-01  3    
33  2019-02-02  2    
34  2019-02-03  1    
35  2019-02-04  1    
... ...         ...
... ...         ...
61  2019-03-02  1    
62  2019-03-03  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a list of dates and `count(distinct)`:

```
select d.dte, count(distinct t.userid) as num_users
from (select distinct purchase_date as dte from t) d left join
     t
     on d.dte >= t.dte and
        d.dte <= t.expiry_date
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

EDIT:

BigQuery can be fickle about inequalities in the `on` clause.  Here is another approach:

```
select dte, count(distinct t.userid) as num_users
from t cross join
     unnest(generate_date_array(t.purchase_date, t.expiry_date, interval 1 day)) dte
group by dte
order by dte;
```

You can use a `where` clause to filter down to particular dates.

Answer (score 0):

I make the table name 'test_expirydate' and use your data 
and this one work

```
select
    tb1.expirydate,
    count(*) as total
from test_expirydate as tb1
left join (
    select
        expirydate
    from test_expirydate as tb2
    group by userid
) as tb2
on tb1.expirydate >= tb2.expirydate
group by tb1.expirydate
```

I don't sure is it work in other case or not but it fine with current data

*Oh, I interpret that the left column should be the expiration date.*